# Materialize not scaling expected on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, materialize

I'm using the [Materialize CSS framework](http://materializecss.com/) for a RoR application. The webpages scale as expected when using Chrome/Firefox dev tools, even when selecting a mobile device (I've used iPhone SE here, but bigger screen sizes yield the same result):

[image]

However upon visiting the site on my actual phone or any other smartphone device, it scales like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what the issue may be? I'm using the framework as-is, v0.100.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

?